# mingw32-make + mklink... just not getting along?

Tags: makefile, mingw, gnu-make, mklink

Not sure if anyone else has gotten this to work, but I'm having no end of trouble even with the following simple line in my Makefile running `mingw32-make`:

`mklink Mk Makefile`

The following created the link, but `mingw32-make` puked and threw error 255 thereafter:

`$(shell cmd /c 'mklink Mk Makefile')`

Nothing else is problematic, and I have a relatively complex makefile. Only `mklink` is doing this. (Apparently msys has it's own problems with `ln` so going down that path appears pointless.)

Comment: AFAIK, `mklink` is a privileged operation on Windows; are you sure your `make` process is sufficiently privileged to invoke it? Other than that, I can think of no reason why it should not work.

Comment: I've provided _two_ answers below, covering the two independent aspects of this question -- arguably it shouldn't have two aspects, but it does. Unfortunately, SO doesn't give me a way to keep the more pertinent above the more recent; I can't vote for my own answers, but the more pertinent needs to be voted up, or maybe even accepted, to promote it.

Comment: @KeithMarshall, Both +1'ed, just need to test before I accept. The additional detail you've kindly provided re MSYS `ln` provides a fallback - superb. Many thanks for all your hard work on MinGW, the project that enables me to develop in the way I consider ideal. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me, (on Win7 Home Premium, in VirtualBox),
*provided* I invoke it in a shell running with administrator privilege:

```
$ cat makefile.tst
all:
        cmd /c "mklink mk makefile.tst"
        @echo "Success!"

$ make -f makefile.tst
cmd /c "mklink mk makefile.tst"
symbolic link created for mk <<===>> makefile.tst
Success!

$ rm mk

$ mingw32-make -f makefile.tst
cmd /c "mklink mk makefile.tst"
symbolic link created for mk <<===>> makefile.tst
Success!
```

My shell, in this case is MSYS `sh.exe`, invoked via `msys.bat` from `cmd.exe` with UAC escalation to administrator privilege. This is so that I can show that the `mklink` command works both in MSYS' own `make.exe`, and in `mingw32-make.exe`; (of course, the `mingw32-make.exe` example also works directly from the elevated `cmd.exe` shell itself).

I suspect that attempting to use `mklink` directly within the makefile, without the `cmd /c` preamble, may not work because `mklink` is a `cmd.exe` built-in, which GNU make may not know to run this way ... it reports a `CreateProcess` failure, because the specified file cannot be found, when I try it.

Your use of make's `$(shell ...)` construct would not work, because that causes make to invoke the command in the wrong phase of operation ... when parsing the makefile itself, and constructing its dependency graph, rather than as a command to run when the containing rule is invoked, where it will now attempt to execute the *output* from the `$(shell ...)` command as a command in its own right; this is clearly *not* what you want!

Comment: "I suspect that attempting to use mklink directly... is a built-in" was what I gathered as well. Parse-vs.-use issue was my newness to `make` speaking loud and clear!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the position with regard to MSYS' own `ln` command: it **does** work as well as can be expected, within the limitations of the versions of Windows on which it was originally implemented. In particular:

```
$ ln fileA fileB
```

creates a file-to-file *hard* link, on file systems such as NTFS, which support such links, and falls back to creating a *copy* on file systems such as FAT, which don't. Also:

```
$ ln dirA dirB
```

fails, as it should; hard linked directories are a recipe for disaster, and are not allowed, (just as they are forbidden on unix platforms). However:

```
$ ln -s fileA refB
```

will **not** create a symbolic link, (because no version of Windows supported them at the time when MSYS was developed, and no one has stepped forward to implement the capability, since they have become available ... although, their implementation still seems flaky, on Vista and Win7 anyway); rather, this command falls back to creating a *hard* link if possible, or a file copy otherwise. Similarly:

```
$ ln -s dirA refB
```

will **not** create a symbolic directory link, and in this case, there is no fall back; it simply and unconditionally fails! (It might be argued that a deep copy of the directory *could* be a suitable fall back action, but it isn't implemented so; instead, the `lndir` command is provided, to facilitate this).